# ANOVA for road accident data

Tags: regression, anova, modeling, count-data

I have a dataset showing the number of road accidents, persons killed and injured classified according to weather conditions(Sunny, Rainy, Foggy, Hail, Others) for 36 states. It kind of looks like the following:[image]

I want to analyse the influence of weather condition on road accidents. My question is:
Should I perform a one way ANOVA, where there are 36 observations(as in 36 states) corresponding to each level of the factor weather condition?
Or, should I perform two-way ANOVA, taking weather condition as one factor and state as another?

Comment: Do you also have some data on traffic intensity, or stand-ins like state number of cars, ... ? Seach data te often analyzed with Poisson regression or other count data models like negbin regression< ... There is a large literature, you could start with [this stored search](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=modeling+traffic+accident+data&btnG=)

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen I appreciate your suggestion and I'll look into it. But for this particular case that I am interested in(effect of weather condition on road accidents) do you think ANOVA will not be appropriate?

Comment: How do you want to do that comparison without information on hours/sun, hours/rainy, etc? You need the accident rate under the different conditions!